# Blockquote doesn't work correctly

Tags: bug, status-declined, google-chrome, windows-7

I select some text and use Blockquote (icon or shortcut).

1. text **stackoverflow**
2. select
3. use Blockquote
4. get this

stackoverflow

stackoverflow> stackoverflowstackoverflow

stackoverflow

**Update**: Sorry, I checked Chrome version and it's 6.0.408.1 dev. It's probably Chrome bug.

Before:

[alt text http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/3718/testbc.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/3718/testbc.png)

After:

[alt text http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/3880/test2hu.png](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/3880/test2hu.png)

However, I can only reproduce this in the latest Dev version as was already mentioned.

Comment: Helps to know which browser and version you are using (esp. if beta)

Comment: I don't think "status-norepro" is appropriate here. I can repro it with no problem, and I suspect the team could as well if any one of them subscribed to the Chrome dev channel. It's fine to say, "It's a bug in Chrome" - but I think it would be worth taking 15 minutes to try to work out exactly what's required to demonstrate the bug and send it to the Chrome team.

Comment: @Jeff Here's the steps to reproduce

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing (was just about to post about it until I say this). I am using a dev verion of chrome 6.0.472.41. And I agree with @Jon Skeet find the problem and report it to the chrome team.

Comment: It's now affecting the beta channel too, not just dev.

Answer (score 6):

This has been bugging me too. I suspect it may be a problem in a beta version of Chrome, however. I don't seem to have the problem on my non-work Windows laptop (Chrome 5.0.375.55) but I *am* seeing it on the dev version of Chrome on my work Linux desktop (which may or may not be the latest public dev version).

I don't know enough about the JavaScript involved to be able to produce a short-but-complete page to reproduce the problem for the Chrome team. I don't think they'd be particularly happy about accepting a bug which has as much JS in as the SO site does :)

EDIT: It turns out that my Windows version is the beta as well, so it looks like it's only the dev channel which is affected right now. More reason to nip it in the bud, IMO :)

Comment: +1 for using Chrome on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

can't reproduce in Chrome 4.1.249.1064

I get

```
> stackoverflow
```

Comment: I think it would be worth having at least one member of the SO team using the Chrome beta channel. If this is a Chrome bug, I'm sure they'd like to know about it...

Comment: If it's a Chrome bug, their test teams should be worrying about it. SO wont be the only site affected. Plus where would you draw the line; I'm sure <0.1% use Chrome Beta here; what other obscure browsers make up more than that but never get tested against the site?

Comment: @Chris S: It depends on how subtle the bug is. If other sites are affected, maybe all those users and websites will take the same attitude of "let someone else fix it". Why wait until it gets *released* with a bug (at which point it will affect many, many more people) instead of spending just a small amount of time helping to improve a significant browser? Note that there's a difference between code in an obscure browser which will *always* be obscure, and code in a browser version which will become non-obscure when it's released.

Comment: @Jon, If someone wants to be generous that's one thing. I just don't think it's SO *responsibility* to test 3rd party beta software. The Beta devs and users should be responsible for testing. It would be useful if there was a more specific feedback mechanism for reporting Beta browser incompatibilities with SO code...

Comment: @Chris S: I wouldn't go so far as to say it's the SO team's *responsibility* - just a good thing to do.